# Prove that Set B is countable - Is this proof correct?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

It seems that I have some issues with the rigor of this proof and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Could someone tell me if this proof is correct and rigorous enough?

Here's the question

> Prove that if B$\subseteq$A and A is countable, then B is countable.

Here's how I proved it:

> Suppose B$\subseteq$A and A is countable. Since A is countable, it is
> finite or denumerable. Considering cases:
>
> Case 1: A is finite. Then A
> $\sim I_n$ where n=|A|. Since B$\subseteq$A, it follows B $\sim I_n$.
> So B is finite. Therefore B is countable.
>
> Case 2: A is  denumerable. $Z^+ \sim$ A. Since B$\subseteq$A, it
> follows $Z^+ \sim$ B. So B is denumerable. Therefore B is countable.
>
> Thus, B is countable as desired.

**$Z^+$ is the positive integers.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

***Update:some clarifications,

$\sim$ means equinumerous

A being countable means A is either finite or denumerable.

A set A is called denumerable If $Z^+$ $\sim$A.

Comment: What is your _definition_ of countable? Because if your definition is "there exists an injective function from the given set into $\Bbb N$", then it's a lot easier than this (take an injection $A\to \Bbb N$, and restrict to $B$).

Comment: @Arthur Clarifications are added above

Answer (score 1):

When you say "Since $B\subseteq A$ it follows $B \sim I_n$" one could consider that merely stating that which was to be proved by inserting "it follows" -- not really a proof.

I would start with the fact that since $A$ is countable there exists a "counting function $C(A)$" (an injective map $C : A \mapsto \Bbb{N} : \forall a, b \in A, C(a) = C(b) \implies a=b $.  Now consider the restriction of that counting function to the the subset $B$, and it is easy to show that this is an injection as well, thus a valid counting function for $B$.

Comment: I added some clarifications about the notation I use in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not terribly familiar with the $\sim$ notation for sets; presumably it means they're in bijection?

At any rate, I think the difficult part of the argument involves infinite subsets of $A$. Consequently, I think you could use more of an argument in this case, rather than "it follows that $Z^+ \sim B$."

For example, if it's because $B \subseteq A$ gives rise to an injective inclusion function, and the composition of injective functions is injective, then say so!

Comment: I added some clarifications above.